# Creating dynamic sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm currently making a package to use grants as a safegaurd, I want to make a search procedure that searches for rows that contain a name/value column like bellow:

```
PROCEDURE "SEARCH"(P_COLUMN IN VARCHAR2(30), P_VALUE IN MYTABLE.{P_COLUMN}%TYPE, 
                   P_REFCUR OUT SYS_REF_CURSER) IS
-- VARIABLES DECLARATION
BEGIN
    -- SOME LOGIC FOR VALIDATION
    OPEN P_REFCUR FOR
        SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE {P_COLUMN} = P_VALUE;
END "SEARCH";
```

How can I define the `P_VALUE`'s type in procedure's signature and create the where clause where the column (`P_COLUMN`) is a variable string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put your command into quotes. Apart from that you should use bind variables.

```
OPEN P_REFCUR FOR
    'SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE '||P_COLUMN||' = :val' USING P_VALUE;
```

And remove any curling brackets `{}`, they are not used in Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It will be great to know if it is possible to use a trick in procedure signature too. I already defined `P_VALUE IN VARCHAR2` as many types can be cast from `VARCHAR2`.